# How to disable SystemServiceServlet configuration in App Engine project?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-plugin-eclipse

The Google Plugin for Eclipse auto-generates these lines in **web.xml** no matter what the project properties are set to:

```
 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
   <param-name>services</param-name>
   <param-value/>
  </init-param>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/_ah/spi/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

Is there a way to prevent the plugin to do that?

Comment: I think it isn't possible, you have to remove it manually, but you really don't want the console admin in local?.

Comment: After removing it, it's regenerated by the plugin with an automatic reformatting of web.xml - that always leads to local changes in the version control view.
And `/_ah/admin/*` is not affected by removing the servlet above. Is it?

Comment: O sorry!! confused `/_ah/spi/*` with  `/_ah/admin/*`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your project Properties, under Builders, if you disable Google App Engine Project Change Notifier, your web.xml won't by modified anymore.
However, not been keen enough to the GAE environment, I can't tell which are the side-effects of disabling this builder.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the above xml from web.xml and add readonly attribute to web

Comment: When you say above, exactly what 'above' do you mean?

Comment: I mean remove the configuration(SystemServiceServlet) added by eclipse plugin. Then set readonly attribute to the web.xml

Comment: This seems to work ... around. Nice catch. It doesn't even log errors to the Error Log view. Maybe, in a future release, it will be fixed.

Comment: It actually does log some errors: 
`javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: java.io.FileNotFoundException at com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.util.XmlUtil.updateWebXml(XmlUtil.java:197)
 at com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.helpers.SwarmServiceCreator.create(SwarmServiceCreator.java:155)`